# What does "n∼1/d" mean?

Tags: k-nn, classifier

Or rather, what is the "~" notation mean? For reference, I'm trying to understand [this section from a sci-kit learn documentation page.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html#the-curse-of-dimensionality)

[image]

Comment: X ~ D, means the random variable X has the probability distribution D

Comment: In this case I think they just mean "approximately" bu `~`: in one dimension we need on average the number of points $n$ to be around $1/d$.